# Who are the users in the default groups

Tags: linux, group

I am learning command line currently in ubuntu Linux and am using a tutorial video that has shown me how to add and delete groups. When I view the groups in /etc/group file after using the command cat /etc/group, I notice that most the groups have no users located to the right of the colon after the group name.

Does this mean that the group has one user and by default that user is the root?

If the group exists by default but has no users, then does that mean that, other than root, no users can utilize the permissions that those default groups provide?

Comment: It was very clear to me what the question was about (See answer and acceptance), so **Voting to reopen...  0:-)**

Comment: linux.die.net/man/8/adduser states: "By default, a group will also be created for the new user..." I checked several usernames that were also group names but the group listing in /etc/group had no users listed yet they were members of their corresponding group.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**`root` always has access to everything so is not part of any group (except the `root` group itself)**

If you create one additional "normal" user on top of the standard admin user you created during the OS install, you will notice that the admin user will be in some groups and the non-admin user will be in none *unless your video tutorial told you to put the user in there*.

instead of doing a `cat /etc/group` you can also do a:

```
groups
```

to know which groups your current user belongs to or:

```
groups some-user
```

to know which groups `some-user` belongs to or:

```
id some-user
```

to show that user's groups and IDs.

**Additional note:** the standard groups are created to make initial system administration easier. E.G. to allow a user to administer printers, you just add him to the `lpadmin` (`l`ine `p`rinter `admin`) group or to have them administer `cifs` shares just add them to the `sambashare` group.

Comment: `id some-user` will also show the groups (along with ids) a user is a part of @Fabby I can't edit your post (because there is just one edit), but the command is: `cat /etc/group` and not `cat /etc/groups`

Comment: @sla3k Thanks for the comment. Amended and 2 **+1**s **;-)**

Comment: `root` is usually a member of the `root` group; that membership doesn’t appear in `/etc/group` because it’s declared in `/etc/passwd` (but does show up in `id`’s output).

Comment: @StephenKitt Thanks for the reminder.  [Facepalm] [Edited](https://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/483065/revisions) that in!